# Leaflet filter with multiple GeoJSON layer properties

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson

Regarding to the following queries

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59141456/leaflet-problem-with-filtering-the-geojson-layers

[GeoJSON filtering based on properties in Leaflet not working](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/343329/geojson-filtering-based-on-properties-in-leaflet-not-working)

I thought about something like multiple filtration by GeoJSON properties in Leaflet.

Regarding to this I used the following code snippet:

```
      filter: function(feature, layer) {   
            return {
            (feature.properties.Type == "MDU" );
            }
           }
```

which filters my GeoJSON feature property.

The problem is, that despite an existing filter option by `Type`, I would like to make the same filtering for property `Status`. This is another feature, which must be filtered inside the 1st one being already filtered.

[image]

So my attepts were:

```
     filter: function(feature, layer) {   
            return {
            (feature.properties.Type == "MDU" )
            (feature.properties.Status == "Completed_and_invoiced" );
            }
           }
```

and

```
     filter: function(feature, layer) {   
            return {
            feature.properties.Type == "MDU",
            feature.properties.Status == "Completed_and_invoiced"
            }
        }
```

None of them works. The console after the 2nd one says:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'

which is not true, because it refers to the

```
feature.properties.Status == "Completed_and_invoiced"
```

and must be there.
The major example comes from here:

http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/filter/filter.html

This is the thing, that I am the most interested in.

However I found something slightly different here:

[Leaflet : filter with condition](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/192303/leaflet-filter-with-condition)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148598/leaflet-update-geojson-filter

which requires set some condition

and here:

https://blogs.kent.ac.uk/websolutions/2015/01/29/filtering-map-markers-with-leaflet-js-a-brief-technical-overview/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rbnlnXIT4eI

This option seems to be interesting:

[Multiple on-the-fly filtering based on markers' features on leaflet](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/307985/multiple-on-the-fly-filtering-based-on-markers-features-on-leaflet)

although it looks like it refers still for 1-level filtering as per above.

Is it possible to expand the `pointToLayer function` filter for more than 1 `return`?

**UPDATE:**

The another way I tried is:

```
  mdu = L.geoJson(data, {   //1st level geoJSON filteration

    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {

        return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
        radius:6,
        opacity: .5,
        //color: "#000",
        color:getColor(feature.properties.Type),
        fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.Type),
        fillOpacity: 0.8

        }).bindTooltip(feature.properties.Owner);
    },
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        },
        filter: function(feature, layer) {   
            return (feature.properties.Type == "MDU" );
        }
        }).addTo(map);


        mducompleted = L.geoJson(mdu, {    // 2nd level of geoJSON filteration

    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {

        return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
        radius:6,
        opacity: .5,
        //color: "#000",
        color:getColor(feature.properties.Type),
        fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.Type),
        fillOpacity: 0.8

        }).bindTooltip(feature.properties.Owner);
    },
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        },
        filter: function(feature, layer) {   
            return (feature.properties.Status == "Completed_and_invoiced" );
        }
        }).addTo(map);
```

The mducompleted layer not exist on the map, whereas the console says:

> DivOverlay.js:173 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild'
>   on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
>       at NewClass._updateContent (DivOverlay.js:173)
>       at NewClass.update (DivOverlay.js:116)
>       at NewClass.onAdd (DivOverlay.js:53)
>       at NewClass.onAdd (Tooltip.js:71)
>       at NewClass._layerAdd (Layer.js:110)
>       at NewClass.whenReady (Map.js:1411)
>       at NewClass.addLayer (Layer.js:172)
>       at NewClass.openTooltip (Tooltip.js:221)
>       at NewClass.openTooltip (Tooltip.js:340)
>       at NewClass._openTooltip (Tooltip.js:406)

Answer (score 0):

In your first two listed attempts for the "filter" function, I would try excluding/removing the curly braces and use a logical AND (&&) operator between both conditionals...

```
(feature.properties.Type == "MDU" ) && (feature.properties.Status == "Completed_and_invoiced" )
```

Make sure to enclose these two conditional statements within parentheses. (Side note: why not use Strict comparison operator, ===).

As well, if errors are appearing using '.' dot syntax, try enclosing the child members in brackets...

```
feature["properties"]["Type"] == "MDU"
```

Hope you find an answer!

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will try first thing in the morning. Just another quick query. How about if I will have about 5 another feature.properties.Status types? Is it possible to write them within one layer and stick to this example:
http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/filter/filter.html
or shall create 5 separate layers with unique geoJSON properties and then bind them together?